# How to access MYSQL server on android using JDBC

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Can someone help me how to properly access MYSQL database using JDBC.Most tutorials seem to be written in Eclipse when I am working on Android Studio. I am also unsure of how to get the ip of mysql server db.
Any help at all would be appreciated.
I am also working on a linux enviornment if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. If its written for eclipse it should be trivial to do it in Android studio without help.  Eclipse vs Android studio doesn't change the code.
2. I would recommend against directly connecting to a database in any app.  The problem is that to do so, you have to put the password to your db on their phone.  At that point you've given up control of your database, anyone can decompile the app and directly connect to your db.  You should access the db via webservices instead, which allow the login info to never leave your hardware.

Comment: Can you instruct me on how to do this?